# WD Green and Software RAID

Tags: hard-drive, software-raid, raid-1

On WD's website it says

> Desktop drives are not recommended for use in RAID environments,
>   please consider using WD Red hard drives for desktop RAID environments
>   or WD datacenter hard drives for rackmount or large RAID
>   configurations.

They recommend that a WD Green HD is not RAIDed. However if I am using Windows OS software RAID does this count (since I'm not using a hardware RAID)?

Comment: There is no specfic technical reason, but the green drives, do spin down by default which is a problem in a raid environment.

Comment: @Ramhound, no they don't; they just park their heads after 7 seconds of inactivity which can quickly wear them out if you are using them in a server that stays on.

Comment: Parking their heads then spin down, in order to save power...

Comment: Green drives also don't have TLER, which can cause problems if one of the disks malfunctions. The Red drives have special firmware and undergo extra validation to ensure reliable operation in RAID. This validation costs a lot of time and money, so even if the disk media on a Red is exactly the same as that on a Green, the cost is recouped through a separate, more expensive product line made for this purpose rather than raising the price of *every* Green drive sold for a feature that is used only in a small minority of configurations. The latter makes *absolutely no business sense*.

Comment: In any case, I personally wouldn't recommend it. The Red drives exist for a reason.

Comment: @DragonLord I appreciate your insight.  I will regard it in my purchase, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, software RAID counts.   Whether its software or hardware RAID, the stresses on the disks is the same.  It is probable that RAID (software or hardware) will work with the disks [ I say probable because some RAID controllers are picky and won't ], but actually doing so will not work well.

While TLER is certainly a good idea for RAIDED drives, software RAID can work without it. ( particularly if the volumes of data are low.) Performance and reliability are decreased though.

I put to you that going against the advertised criteria of a disk is not a good idea, particularly as the savings are small.

Comment: A good answer, I'll just add that WD Green drives are optimized for use a secondary storage. To save energy they spin down more often than other drives and this would result in slower access time and could generally cause problems in RAID environment.